# How can order the ArrayList with multiple type of Object

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create a list with multipe type of Object. So I have built this code:

```
List<Entrate>lista = modelManager.getEntrataManager().getEntrate();
List<NotaSpese>listaSpese=modelManager.getNotaSpesaManager().getNotaSpese();

List<Object> listaMovimenti = new ArrayList<Object>();
listaMovimenti.addAll(lista);
listaMovimenti.addAll(listaSpese);
```

Now I want to order this collection by the field Data of Entrate and NotaSpese.

How can I to order the List?

Comment: Implement a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and call [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: so, I should to implement the Comparator for Entrata and NotaSpese class?

Comment: yes. But you better work out your object model. Its not advisable to have List<Object>

Comment: See @Seelenvirtuose answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a custom [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
final class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // implement some logic for comparing and return an int value here
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use the method [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-):

```
List<Object> listaMovimenti = ...
Collections.sort(listaMovimenti, new CustomComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all its not advisable to have collections with mixed types.

but in your case, you should implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface for each type you want to have in the collection. Alternatively you can create a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that would be called during sorting to compare your different types.

Then you can sort with Collections.sort

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally have both `Entrate` and `NotaSpese` be comparable to each other if that's the general usage:

```
class Entrate implements Comparable<Entrate>, Comparable<NotaSpece> { 
     //Implementation with the comparers
}

class NotaSpese implements Comparable<Entrate>, Comparable<NotaSpece> { 
     //Implementation with the comparers   
}
```

Calling `Collections.sort(listaMovimenti)` would then use the appropirate comparers.

Hopefully I haven't missed something.